# Node js express res.json() return html not json

Tags: node.js, express

I have problem when a call router.get(), i am returning to response json using res.json() but it return html 
here is my api.js

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var marklogic = require("marklogic");
var conn = require('../env.js').connection;

var db = marklogic.createDatabaseClient(conn);

router.route('/akt')

    // Vraca usvojene akte
    .get(function (req, res) {
        res.json({message: 'TODO vraca usvojene akte'});
    })

    // Predlaganje akta
    .post(function (req, res) {

        db.documents.write(
        {
            uri: '/korisnik/1.xml',
            contentType: 'application/xml',
            collections: 'korisnik',
            content: '<entry-list><entry id="horror2"></entry></entry-list>'
        })

    })

    // Povlaci predlog akta
    .delete(function (req, res) {
        res.send({message: "TODO povlaci predlog akta"});
    });


router.route('/amandman/:akd_id')

    // Predlog amandmana na predlog akta
    .post(function (req, res) {
        res.send({message: 'TODO predlaganje amandmana na predlog akta'});
    })

    // Povlaci predlog amandmana
    .delete(function (req, res) {
        res.send({message: 'TODO povlaci predlog amandmana'});
    });



module.exports = router;
```

Please can somebody tell me where is my error, also if you need some more file I will give it.

Edit:
I noticed when I remove from server.js this lines everything works, why is that?

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Just use `res.json()` to send JSON structures

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
})
```

to

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
})
```

You match every route to `index.html` when using `*` regular expression.

Comment: If you change that, then you will not delegate the routing to the client app. This is not possible.