# Getting an Array with Angular 2 from mongoose mongoDB database

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose

I am trying to retrieve my Members collection in my angular 2 front end.

in my routes I have:

```
router.post('/memberprofile', function (req, res) {
    Member.find({}, function (err, members){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
           res.json(members);
           console.log('retrieved members', members.length);
           console.log(members);
        }
   });
});
```

I am attempting to GET it by using this code:

```
export class MemberprofileComponent implements OnInit {
      member:Object;
      members:Array<Object>;
      result:Array<Object>;
      constructor(
      private authService:AuthService,
      private router:Router,
      private http:Http
      ) {
 this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/memberprofile')
              .subscribe(result => this.result = result.json());
              console.log(this.result);
               }
```

I am then given the following error in the console:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

[Screenshot of Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92EnI.png)

[Screenshot of Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUgOB.png)

My question is, how am I able to push the array to the front end, I hope to eventually place the result into a table but at the moment if anyone can work out why I cant console log this array that would be great.

Comment: Can you show server response body (e.g. screenshot from network tab)?

Comment: @Leguest I have added it to the original question, thanks

Comment: Yes, that is nice, but I am pointing at `users/memberprofile` response, http://joxi.ru/5mdvvakukKvEZA, click on it and find tab `preview` or `Response`

Comment: @Leguest is that ok? Iv added to OP

Comment: Yes, it is clear now. As you can see server returns index.html page instead of json data. I think problem in server configuration

Comment: @Leguest do you have any idea how I can figure this out? I understand what you mean by it displaying the index page, I just dont understand how it isn't getting the JSON

Comment: What server do you use? e.g. nginx, apache, express

Comment: I am using Node.js and Express.js @Leguest

Comment: I am not sure, but look at this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37877243/node-js-express-res-json-return-html-not-json. I can help you more if you provide your `server.js` code