# After deploying React app to Heroku from dev env, Fetch requests broken - all GET requests returning index.html - others are 404

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, deployment

I have just deployed my Create-React-App project to Heroku. In development, I was running two separate ports - the local HTML + JS were being served from the React `WebpackDevServer` using the `npm/yarn start` scripts on Port 3000. The Backend was Express + NodeJS running on port 3001. I configured all fetch requests to use `mode:'cors'` and provided a handler on the API so to avoid CORS errors. 
A typical fetch request would look like this:

When I deployed to Heroku, everything is now kept together on a single Dyno, and the Express app serves the React files (bundle + index.html) and also handles backend routing logic.

Here is a sample of my API code so-far:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const config = require('./models/config');
require('dotenv').config()
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);

const storeItems= require('./controllers/storeItems')
const authorize= require('./controllers/authorize')
const router = express.Router(); 

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; 
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${process.env.MLABS_USER}:${process.env.MLABS_PW}@ds113000.mlab.com:13000/omninova`, { useMongoClient: true });

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Middleware to handle CORS in development:

app.use('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, x-access-token, x-user-pathway, x-mongo-key, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
  next();
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

router.route('/api/storeItem/')
    .get(storeItems.getAllStoreItems)
    .post(storeItems.createNewStoreItem);

router.route('/authorize')
    .post(authorize.login);

// Catch-All Handler should send Client index.html for any request that does not match previous routes

router.route('*')
    .get((req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
    });

app.use('/', router);

server.listen(config.port);
module.exports = app;
```

I'm having some issues, ALL of my get requests are returning my index.html page with the following Error: `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

I have the following Fetch Request:

```
    return fetch(`/api/storeItem`, {
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'no-cors',
    })
    .then(response => response.ok ? response.json() : Promise.reject(response))
    .then(json => {
        dispatch(receiveItems(json))
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

This is failing, because instead of triggering the Express Middleware that should be running `storeItems.getAllStoreItems` on the backend, It's passing that route and triggering the catch-all handler, which I use to serve the index.html upon initial request:

```
router.route('*')
    .get((req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
    });
```

Another confusion is that this following fetch request returns a 404, even though the `/authorize` route is expecting a POST request in the API code:

```
export function attemptLogIn(credentials) {
    return dispatch => {
        return fetch('/authorize', {
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors'
        body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
        })
        .then(response => response.ok ? response.json() : Promise.reject(response.statusText))
        .then(json => {
            dispatch(routeUserAfterLogin(json.accountType))
        })
        .catch(err => dispatch(authFail(err.message)))
    }
}
```

Any help with this would be highly appreciated. I assume I am doing something wrong with the Express Router, since the authorize route is just not being picked up.

I followed the instructions in this blog post to help me set up my new project: `https://daveceddia.com/deploy-react-express-app-heroku/`

Edit: This is Fetch code from my Development branch. This successfully logs the user in, without returning a 404. However, I do not use the catch-all handler at all, or the express.static middleware:

```
return fetch('http://localhost:3001/authorize', {
    headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors', 
    body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
})
```

Edit: I just changed the URL which points to the bundle.js to 
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../../build')));`
I'm not sure how I was even sending out the HTML before, since that's the actual location of build files..I'm not sure how they were being found before.

Edit2: Found my problem, I left in the start script for my React project (which actually started the webpack dev server...)

Answer (score 2):

For the first part

> Error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

My guess is that without the dev server, express can't handle the bundle download automatically. So, when your index.html hits `/path/to/bundle.js`, it falls under the wildcard ("*") route, which returns the HTML itself. Your browser then tries to parse it as JS, but it can't since it's HTML, hence the error.

I would try something like:

```
app.get("path/to/bundle.js", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("path/to/bundle.js");
});
```

Comment: Tyvm for your response! In My Heroku Logs, I can see that the bundle has been downloaded: `heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/bundle.js" host=still-beach-13809.herokuapp.com request_id=9... dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=304 bytes=176 protocol=http`. If the bundle.js was not there, I don't think I would be able to access my React Javascript code (fetch requests etc), I can also see bundle.js in Sources tab. I believe the problem is fetch requests (GET) which should be going to to `/storeItems` still goes to that wildcard route and triggers res.sendFile(index.html)

Comment: hmm I see. But this express configuration is working on local but not on prod? Same code? Because it looks alright to me

Comment: I do not have the following code in dev: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));` or `router.route('*')
    .get((req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
    });` in prod. After I added that, all my GET requests are triggering this.

Comment: I would try moving this line `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));` right before `router.route('*')` and make sure the wildcard route is the last one defined - in express the order matters

Comment: I'm not sure why it is not working :( I have the following 3 routes: 
`app.get('/storeItem/', storeItems.getAllStoreItems);`
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));` 
`app.get('*', (req, res) => {res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));});`. 
Now, here is my fetch...it should work to retrieve JSON, but It gets HTML 
`return fetch('/storeItem/', {headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json',},method: 'GET',mode: 'no-cors',})`. Still not understanding why it is not being properly matched. Maybe some proxy issue or error with my code/build

Comment: I will try a new boilerplate project from scratch to make sure that I have configured this one correctly. And maybe it would be easier to serve the React project from some static generator and have the express running alone from heroku and not serving the html

Answer (score 1):

Your server is not sending json response but HTML content. Change response to res.text() and log it.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```
router.route('*')
    .get((req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This should fix the problem. Instead of "*" there should be "/". Now my GET request works like the POST on Heroku.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37878281/12839684

Comment: You saved me! Big thanks to you, I can finally go to sleep :)